# Could not find class 'net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner' referenced method com.rockers.entrymanager.CameraTestActivity.onCreate

Tags: android, zbar

when i click on the scan my application is stopped. I have also import that.

```
/* Import ZBar Class files */
import net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Image;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.SymbolSet;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's late but I solved a similar problem by importing in libs folder armeabi folder which has libiconv.so and libzbarjni.so inside, also armeabi-v7a folder with same files inside and lastly x86 folder again with the same files